# Do virus author's purposely speak in broken English to avoid linguistic evidence?

Tags: malware, antimalware

Are there any examples of native English speakers creating a virus with broken English on purpose?

Comment: fake bad english would likely be more unique than specifically broken english.

Comment: I do it sometimes when doing market research and pretending to be client from overseas.

Comment: You should take a look at the english shadow broker's broken english. It makes you think they write that way on purpose.

Comment: There is a way to do this programmatically while randomising the key linguistic factor: write your message in language A (A can be English), use Google Translate to convert to a random language B, then translate to English. This should eliminate all linguistic markers, is cheap, easy, and randomised. Not an example, but shows how easy it is to do.

Answer (score 1):

False flagging is a common methodology to throw off defenders when trying to attribute TTP’s.